# Can we implement a link list without using the head pointer means by using a simple variable of the head instead of the pointer of the head?

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list

Can we implement a link list without using the head pointer means by using a simple variable of the head instead of the pointer of the head ?

Comment: What does an empty list look like?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. If you are implementing a circular linked list with a sentinel node, the sentinel node can be the simple variable that also serves as the head.

Alternatively, you could use a `std::optional` instance to serve as the head.

Answer (score 1):

In specific cases you *could*, but in general not. And why would you want to? Here are some reasons, I could think of now. Take for example this code:

```
template<class T>
class Node
{
  private:
    T value;
    Node<T> *next;
};

class MyLinkedList
{
  private:
    bool isEmpty; // indicates wether the list is empty or not
    Node head;  // Head as member
};
```

**But there are several major flaws with this code:**

1. You would always need to care about `isEmpty` when adding or deleting, or doing anything with the list
2. You can't initialize `head` if `T` has no default constructor
3. When deleting the last element you have to call the destructor of object that technically remains in scope.
4. When deleting the last element and then deleting the empty list the destructor of `Node::value` will be called twice

Don't know if those are all reasons, but I think, just #2 is a big enough problem to not consider this.

Of course you could use [std::optional](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional), <del>but that's just a pointer with a wrapper.</del> which even works, without a default constructor, so could be an alternative. Alltough it would be used in the same way as a (smart) pointer, so it's not *"a simple variable of the head"*.

Comment: From your link: ... "the value is guaranteed to be allocated as part of the optional object footprint, i.e. no dynamic memory allocation ever takes place"

Comment: @jxh Shame on me, I didn't think this was possible, but you're right.